# How to use DO statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I am attempting to get a better understanding of the `DO` statement in postgreSQL 9.1.

I have following code block:

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF 1=1 THEN
SELECT 'foo';
ELSE
SELECT 'bar';
END IF;
END
$do$
```

However, it returns the following error:

```
[42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead. Where: PL/pgSQL function "inline_code_block" line 4 at SQL statement
```

Comment: You can't do a `SELECT` in a `DO` block without putting the result of the `SELECT` somewhere or doing something with it. `SELECT 'foo'` in a `DO` block will not display 'foo' on your screen. Data is displayed via `RAISE NOTICE` and the like. If you want to select something and discard the result, use `PERFORM`: `PERFORM 'foo'`

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL `DO` command creates and executes some specific short life function. This function has not any interface, and then it cannot to return any output other then changes data in tables and some debug output.

Your example has more than one issues:

1. Only PostgreSQL table functions can returns some tabular data. But the mechanism is significantly different than MSSQL. PostgreSQL user's should to use `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` commands.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(a int)
   RETURNS TABLE(b int, c int) AS $$
   BEGIN
     RETURN QUERY SELECT i, i + 1 FROM generate_series(1,a) g(i);
   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

   SELECT * FROM foo(10);
   ```
2. `DO` anonymous functions are not table functions - so no output is allowed.
3. PostgreSQL 9.1 is not supported version, please upgrade

If you have some experience only from MSSQL, then forget it. A concept of stored procedures of PostgreSQL is very similar to Oracle or DB2, and it is significantly different to MSSQL does. T-SQL integrates procedural and SQL constructs to one set. Oracle, PostgreSQL, ... procedural functionality can embedded SQL, but procedural functionality is not integrated to SQL.

Please, read PostgreSQL PLpgSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) for better imagine about this technology.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num INTEGER
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `0` into `test` table as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (0);
```

Now, you can create the `DO` statement which increments `num` by `1`, then raises a message with [RAISE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) as shown below:

```sql
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE
  value INTEGER;
BEGIN
  UPDATE test SET num = num + 1;
  SELECT num INTO value FROM test;
  RAISE INFO 'value is %.', value;
END
$$;
```

Then, running the `DO` statement above gets the output below:

> INFO:  value is 1.
> DO