# Getting Error "query has no destination for result data"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I trying to select query based on condition using IF ElSE in postgres. Below is my query.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE res varchar(50) := 'a';
BEGIN
IF (res = 'a') THEN
SELECT "Name" FROM "TestTable";
ELSE 
SELECT "ID" FROM "TestTable";
END IF;
END
$do$
```

but I am getting following error

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at SQL statement
```

What I am doing wrong here??

Comment: See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+query+has+no+destination+for+result+data)

Comment: there it is returning text and I want to return SELECT Query

Comment: Did you go through **all** of those answers in just one minute?

Comment: ohh sorry, I just saw the First answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51862221

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you please help me in restructuring my query, because I never used Postgres earlier and not able to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180500/discussion-between-navy-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 3):

[`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) purpose is to execute anonymous code block and it doesn't return anything (it returns void, to be specific).

You can execute your `SELECT` statement afterwards (outside of `DO` block), or perform an `INSERT` to temporary table which you need to create beforehand (and this can be done within the block).